# Setting order of Activities and going back from them

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a few activities:

- Splash screen
- Login
- Registration
- Dashboard

If the user has never logged in, it will go like this:

> Splash screen > Login > Registration > Dashboard

When I `back` from the Dashboard, it should exit the app, skipping through the other activities.

`noHistory` on the Login page doesn't work here because sometimes the user will `back` from Registration.

If the user has previously logged on, it should go like this:

> Splash screen > Dashboard

If the user logs out, perhaps to use another account, then it should go:

> Dashboard > Login > Dashboard

But if the user goes `back` from the new Dashboard, it shouldn't enter the previous account's Dashboard.

Aside from that, my app contains multiple modules, some of which don't have access to other modules, so a solution that can work between modules would be helpful.

I have tried a mix of `finish()` and `startActivityForResult()` and trying to check where the activities return from but it felt very hacky, time-consuming, and it messes up on new use cases. Are there better ways?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);

Comment: Add the above lines in splash and login screen

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

In your splash activity I have a method like :

```
   @Override
public void loadLoginScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```

Then in Login activity (i am using firebase so i check if the user is null or not you may apply your logic to check the same )

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Get Firebase auth instance
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
      startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class));
      finish();
    }
    // set the view now
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
 }
```

and when I do the logout I do somewhat like this

```
     @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

      case R.id.milogout:
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(LoginActivity.class);
        finish();
        break;

    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me because I have my Login page on a different module from the Dashboard, so I'm unable to open the Dashboard with it.

Answer (score 1):

Previous activities need to be finished on moving to **Dashboard**. Call before starting new activity of Dashboard

```
finishAffinity();
```

This finish current activity as well as all activities immediately below it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this function existed

Comment: @Muz did this work for you?